# How to carry the token in the headers using $resource？

Tags: angularjs, jwt, ngresource

I succeeded in using this command to get the data in terminal.

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT some-token-code" localhost:8001/api/users/
```

But in angular1.x `app.factory.js`.It returns `GET http://localhost:8001/api/users/ 401 (Unauthorized)`

```
function(token) {
                console.log('JWT ' + token)
                return $resource("/api/users/ ", {}, {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token
                    }
                })
            }
```

This is the request headers

`GET /api/users/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8001/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Cookie: JESONG_USER_ID=01000000003981226574343581913557; _ga=GA1.1.630936919.1492924579; __utma=1.630936919.1492924579.1492924580.1492924580.1; __utmz=1.1492924580.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); Hm_lvt_a5aaaf14eb4ea4f77e46c672b6e33b31=1492924579; Hm_lvt_e010d1faf316a4dbfe8639481a2a3f90=1492930657; sessionid=ic2svmb4wyec67gz1opv5xbpl8fvc1vr; csrftoken=pQWQTS0xhk7hY5d1m3OABxbDPIFbkLSI3kDC0bcIwCDzm0wEmjsu6PbFsalfMgnz; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBhLmNjIiwiZXhwIjoxNDk0NjY3NDI5fQ.Zs2fwu97QvyWqL1dzuf6VSfLLDOsbs-M6KeIy2cSpIg; username=admin; name=; identity=%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E5%91%98`

I do not know where the problem is.

How can i use $ resource to simulate HTTP requests in the command line (how to configure headers)?

Beginner, thank you for your teaching.